# How to cherry-pick then mark branch as merged w/o adding to commit history?

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

We used to use svn. We built and released from "release" branches, then selectively merged back into trunk (in TortoiseSVN, by checking or unchecking commits during the merge). Now, after converting to git, we do the same but are merging like this:

- cherry-pick commits from the release branch into master
- merge -s ours release-branch --log --no-edit -m"marking branch as merged"

Which does what we want, at least functionally. However, since the commits in the "ours" merge are actually getting "merged" (without changing anything), they end up in the commit history for master--which makes the commit history very confusing.

Is there a way to suppress or customize the writing of "merged" commits to the target branch (master, in this case)? Suppressing would be nice, but pre-pending the commit message with "ignore, merged as 'ours': " or similar would at least help.

EDIT: From @phd's answer, it's apparent that I wasn't reading the resultant commit log correctly, but that `--first-parent master` filters the log down to what I want.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand: you’re going out of your way to do a useless merge - that only has the effect of recording a merge in history and not changing the tree.  But you want to not write that merge commit that you just intentionally did?  There’s a piece to your question that I’m missing...  why are you doing this merge -sours in the first place?  Why don’t you just delete that branch and be done with it?

Comment: Good question. We will delete feature or scratch branches once merged (and obsolete), but we keep these "release" branches around in case an emergency release is needed before the next official "release" is taken to production. So after a production release (R1) we "merge" it back into master, sync it out to test environments, and can continue working in master for the next official release (will eventually be created as R2). But if a hotfix is needed, we apply it to R1 and re-release R1 without the danger of releasing any deltas from master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> end up in the commit history for master

That depends on the way you view said commit history. The command

```
git log --first-parent master
```

shows commits that belong to master only.

> which makes the commit history very confusing.

I recommend you to accommodate to merged branches, after that they will not be confused at all. Merging is quite a standard operation in git so accommodating yourself to merged branches is the best you can do.

> Is there a way to suppress or customize the writing of "merged" commits to the target branch

There is no. BTW `git` doesn't write commits from a merged branch into master — it creates a merge commit that simply point to both branches and that's how git history viewers (including `git log`) discover commits from the merged branch.

Comment: Thanks @phd. This was helpful, especially `--first-parent master`. However, what do you mean that you "recommend [me] to accommodate to merged branches" ...?

Comment: Git is not Subversion, and merging in git is rather different from SVN. Do not try to recreate you SVN workflow in git. Instead develop a git-oriented workflow. For one you need to understand in what way merging is different in git.